# take a partial screenshot on button press

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I am trying to take a partial screenshot with a button press and save it to camera roll.

I have code that I found from another question but pressing the button crashes the app.

```
// Declare the snapshot boundaries
let top: CGFloat = 100
let bottom: CGFloat = 0

// The size of the cropped image
let size = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height - top - bottom)

// Start the context
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)

// we are going to use context in a couple of places
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

// Transform the context so that anything drawn into it is displaced "top" pixels up

context.translateBy(x: 0, y: -top)

// Draw the view into the context (this is the snapshot)
view.layer.render(in: context)
let snapshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

// End the context (this is required to not leak resources)
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

// Save to photos
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(snapshot!, nil, nil, nil)
```

Comment: Did you debug this code which line was crashed? did you setted outlet or added selector correctly for button?

Comment: Could you please share the crash log.

Comment: @iasla issue resolve?

Comment: not yet. I am working on other parts of my app until I can find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Call with argument your screen shot view in this function:-

```
func imageWithView(view: UIView) -> UIImage {
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0)
     view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
     let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
     return img
}
```